# Vim macro to get html skeleton?

Tags: vim, macros

I created a macro to just get what was in the tags of each line in an html file. My macro was

```
j0yf\>f\>maGp\`alf< y$Gpo^[`a]
```

It works whenever I type the commands manually, but when I execute it via the macro I just get an error beep and only the skeleton of the first line is copied and pasted.

By the way, in order for it to work there has to be a space at the end of each line. I know it's not very efficient. I was just experimenting, and now I'm confused because the manual commands work when the macro doesn't.

#### Edit:

Do macros ignore errors? That might be why I can manually get the skeleton because when I manually enter the commands I force vim to ignore the errors.

Comment: As a suggestion, you might want to use XPath or XQuery to process HTML/XML files.

Comment: Do you want to get all the structure without the content pasted at the end of the buffer? Yes macros stop on errors. Just so you know, you can yank `<tag>` with `ya<`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macros do not ignore errors. Instead, they cease when they encounter an error. In contrast, the `:%norm` command just moves on to the next line when it encounters an error, so you might try using `` :%norm j0yf>f>maGp`alf< y$Gpo^[`a] ``.

Comment: Could you tell me where in the help files this information is? I tried looking up :help macros but nothing like this came up

Comment: `:help recording` or `:help q` and `:help :norm` give some information regarding this.